# filter two values in list of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a filter list that I have two fields. The first is the typical filter which is whether or not containing part of or letters written to an input. And the other is if what is written in the input is exactly like a code shows a result.

In the second case, the items are hidden so the only way to see them entering a unique code that only few users have access. (customer requirements)

This works very well, but when you write some filter will not charge erasing all the items you should, just some. I'll let my code and images.

My list :

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Buscar" ng-model="search.name">
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="lugar in organizations_all | lugares:search track by lugar.id" ng-click="mostrarAreas(lugar.id)">
```

My filter :

```
.filter('lugares', function() {
return function(items,filtro) {
  var lugares = [];
  if(typeof filtro == "undefined" || filtro == ""){
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(!item.hide){
        lugares.push(item);
      }

    });
  }else{
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.code == filtro.name && item.hide == true) {
        lugares.push(item);
      }else{
        if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filtro.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && item.code == "" && item.hide == false){
          lugares.push(item);
        }
      }
    });
    if(filtro.name == "" || typeof filtro.name == "undefined"){
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(!item.hide){
          lugares.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return lugares;
 }
})
```

Comment: A simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo would be a lot more effective than a whole bunch of images

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I can not simulate the same code as everything is consumed from a webservice client, confidential information, etc.

Comment: There are numerous dummy data services you can use and even copying data structure with a few dummy values in hard coded array can be done. A question here about filtering arrays is not much good without sample data to test against

Comment: All right, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Repost :

```
.filter('lugar', function(){
```

return function(items, filtro){

```
console.log("ENTRO");
var lugares = [];
if(filtro == "" || typeof filtro == "undefined"){
  lugares = [];
  angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(!item.hide){
        lugares.push(item);
      }
    });
  return lugares;
}else{
  angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if(item.code == filtro.name && item.hide == true) {
      lugares.push(item);
    }else{
      if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filtro.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && item.code == "" && item.hide == false){
        lugares.push(item);
      }
    }
  });
  return lugares;
}
}
})
```